# How to pass array with all elements with jquery to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I am trying to pass an array from jQuery to PHP.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="name1" name="name[]" value="name1"> Name1
<input type="checkbox" id="name2" name="name[]" value="name2"> Name2
<input type="checkbox" id="name3" name="name[]" value="name3"> Name3<br />

<input type="checkbox" id="phone1" name="phone[]" value="samsung"> Samsung
<input type="checkbox" id="phone2" name="phone[]" value="nokia"> Nokia
<input type="checkbox" id="phone3" name="phone[]" value="motorola"> Motorola<br />
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(":checkbox").on('change', function() {
        var group = [];
        var mygroup = {};

        $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){    
            var val = this.value;
            var name = this.name;   
            mygroup[name] = val;
            var all = name + "=" + val;
            group.push(all);

            $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST", 
                url: 'testdraft1.php',
                data: mygroup, // TRIED WITH group and all also. Doesn't work.
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#result").html(data);
                }
            });     
        });
    });
});
```

With this code the array is passed to PHP but with only 1 element. Even if I select multiple elements. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: all your inputs have the same id and name. Change that

Comment: It's because your are initializing the array every time there is a change in checkbox. Move the array outside of `$(":checkbox").on('change', function() {`

Comment: Changed that, still does the same. Still not including all the elements.

Comment: The issue is because you're overwriting the property of the object each time because the checkboxes all have the same name. You're also sending an AJAX request for every individual checked box, which I don't believe is what you want.

Comment: BTW, this code makes *n* AJAX requests every time a checkbox is changed, where *n* is the number of checkboxes that are currently checked.

Comment: I want the data to be sent everytime a checkbox is checked/unchecked. So I have included the AJAC call in the change function. What changes should I make to the name[] ?

Comment: The AJAX call should be in the change function but not in the `each` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works and is perhaps simpler than using `FormData`. (Note that I've changed `name[]` to `name` and `phone[]` to `phone`.) I've also moved the AJAX call outside of the `each` loop.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="name1" name="name" value="name1"> Name1
<input type="checkbox" id="name2" name="name" value="name2"> Name2
<input type="checkbox" id="name3" name="name" value="name3"> Name3<br />

<input type="checkbox" id="phone1" name="phone" value="samsung"> Samsung
<input type="checkbox" id="phone2" name="phone" value="nokia"> Nokia
<input type="checkbox" id="phone3" name="phone" value="motorola"> Motorola<br />
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(":checkbox").on('change', function() {
        var mygroup = {};

        $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i) {
            var val = this.value;
            var name = this.name;

            mygroup[name] = (mygroup[name] || []).concat([val]);
        });

        $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST", 
            url: 'testdraft1.php',
            data: mygroup,
            success: function(data) {
                $("#result").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

This line is a bit confusing:

```
mygroup[name] = (mygroup[name] || []).concat([val]);
```

Here's a simpler version of it:

```
// initialize with an empty array if needed
if (mygroup[name] === undefined) {
    mygroup[name] = [];
}
// append the most recent value to the array
mygroup[name].push(val);
```

Comment: @Pugazh @smarx Thank u masters thanks a million

didnt understand th concat so did the following & works perfect.

`$(document).ready(function() {
 $(":checkbox").on('change', function() {

 var mygroup = {};
 
  $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){ 
 
  var val= this.value;
  var name = this.name; 
  
  mygroup[name]=val;
 });
 
 $.ajax({ 
  type: "POST", 
  url: 'testdraft1.php',
  data : mygroup,    
  success: function(data){
  $("#result").html(data);
    }
  });  
 
 });
   
});`

Tried both codes n giving same result
Happy its working
golly what a day

Comment: @Somename That code can't possibly work. Are you sure it works when you've checked more than one checkbox in the same group? (More than one `name` or more than one `phone`?)

Comment: @Somename See my edit, where I added a simpler alternative for that line.

Comment: How can I pass a variable for pagination with the same code? Can I do ajax post and getJSON in the same query?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the ajax post inside the each loop, which means if you check five boxes you will send a separate post for every iteration of the each call.

That means the first post will have just one checkbox, the second post will have two, etc.

Unless you really want to do that, then you need to close your each loop before your  ajax call.

That doesn't solve the name problem, but it will solve the reason you only get one checkbox sent to php.

Comment: None of the calls will have more than one checkbox per name (`name[]` or `phone[]`), since `mygroup` can only have one value per key.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple of problems with your code,

1. AJAX code should be outside `.each` function.
2. Define array outside `change` event.
3. You can't send array direct like this in AJAX request. Use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData) for that.

So change your code like this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var group = []; //DEFINED THE ARRAY
        $(":checkbox").on('change', function() {
            $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i) {
                var val = this.value;
                var name = this.name;
            var dataObject = {};
            dataObject.name = name;
            dataObject.val = val;

            group.push(dataObject);

        });
        var fd = new FormData();
        for (var i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {
            fd.append(group[i].name, group[i].val);
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'testdraft1.php',
            data: fd,
            success: function(data) {
                $("#result").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: "You can't send array direct like this in AJAX request. Use FormData for that." Actually, see my answer. It turns out jQuery handles arrays of values in much the way PHP expects. (If you send `{ foo: [1, 2, 3] }`, jQuery encodes that to `foo[]=1&foo[]=2&foo[]=3`, which is PHP's convention.)

Comment: That's true. We can send like this too `{ foo: [1, 2, 3] }`

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="name1" name="name[]" value="name1"> Name1
<input type="checkbox" id="name2" name="name[]" value="name2"> Name2
<input type="checkbox" id="name3" name="name[]" value="name3"> Name3

<br />

<input type="checkbox" id="phone1" name="phone[]" value="samsung"> Samsung
<input type="checkbox" id="phone2" name="phone[]" value="nokia"> Nokia
<input type="checkbox" id="phone3" name="phone[]" value="motorola"> Motorola

<br />


$(document).ready(function() {
    $(":checkbox").on('change', function() {

    var group=[];   //DEFINED THE ARRAY
    var mygroup = {};  // DEFINED THE OBJECT

        $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){    

        var val= this.value;
        var id = this.id;   

        mygroup[id]=val;  //PUSH VALUES TO THE OBJECT mygroup

        var all = id+"="+val;

        group.push(all); // PUSH ALL CHECKBOX VALUES TO ARRAY

    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: 'testdraft1.php',
        data : mygroup,             //TRIED WITH group and all also. Doesn't work.
        success: function(data){
        $("#result").html(data);
    }
   });  

    });
    });

});
```

Use same Name but rather changing the name you change the id name it will works for you